# Reactive variable is undefined when it is defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to get some help debugging a situation where a Reactive Variable is undefined, when it has been defined already.

This code is attaching a Reactive Variable to the template instance, and using the variable in `template.autorun()`.

```
Template.home.onCreated(function () {
  this.limit = new ReactiveVar(15);

  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscribe('recent-topics', this.limit.get());
  });
});
```

When I load the template for the first time, I expect the template to subscribe to `recent-topics` with an argument `15`. However, the code throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue.

Inside of your Tracker.autorun, this no longer refers to the template, but the autorun's callback function. Inside of the autorun, try calling Template.instance().limit.get().

Comment: Thanks. Using `Template.instance()` worked. Resolved by saving a reference to the original `this` in a variable `self` and using it.

Answer (score 3):

Just an answer for the sake of spreading the joys of ES6:

```
Template.home.onCreated(function () {
  this.limit = new ReactiveVar(15);

  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('recent-topics', this.limit.get());
  });
});
```

Make sure you add the `grigio:babel` package, and your Javascript file ends in `.es6.js`, `.es6`, or `.jsx`.

### Explanation

In ES6 (aka ECMAScript 6), there's a new "fat arrow" syntax which is very similar to CoffeeScript's implementation. In ES6, when you do something like this:

```
someFunc = function () {
  anotherThing((var1, var2) => {
    this.thing = true;
  });
};
```

It's the same as doing this:

```
someFunc = function () {
  var self = this;

  anotherThing(function (var1, var2) {
    self.thing = true;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Better than using `Template.instance().limit.get()` (ryan's answer)

You should do something like this:

```
Template.home.onCreated(function () {
  var self = this;
  self.limit = new ReactiveVar(15);

  self.autorun(function () {
    self.subscribe('recent-topics', self.limit.get());
  });
});
```